# Cadastrar vários registros usando o mesmo formulário

Tags: php, html, sql

Tenho um formulário de cadastro de clientes onde é possível cadastrar um cliente de cada vez,  como faço pra cadastrar dois cliente por exemplo de uma vez só usando esse mesmo formulário? Testei colocar mais um input, porém só cadastra o último registro.

formulario.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Cadastro de Usuário </title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="cadastro.php">
<label>Nome:</label><input type="text" name="nome" id="nome"><br>
<label>Sobrenome:</label><input type="text" name="sobrenome" id="sobrenome"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" id="cadastrar" name="cadastrar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?php 

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];


$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
$db = mysql_select_db('painel2');

$query_select = "SELECT nome FROM clientes WHERE nome = '$nome'";
$select = mysql_query($query_select,$connect);
$array = mysql_fetch_array($select);
$logarray = $array['nome'];

  if($nome == "" || $nome == null){
    echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('O campo nome deve ser preenchido');window.location.href='formulario.php';</script>";

    }else{
      if($logarray == $nome){

        echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Esse nome já existe');window.location.href='formulario.php';</script>";
        die();

      }else{
        $query = "INSERT INTO clientes (nome,sobrenome) VALUES ('$nome','$sobrenome')";
        $insert = mysql_query($query,$connect);

        if($insert){
          echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!');window.location.href='formulario.php'</script>";
        }else{
          echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Não foi possível cadastrar esse cliente');window.location.href='formulario.php'</script>";
        }
      }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem, vc quer que tenha mais campos onde possam ser inseridos outros nomes?

Comment: isso mesmo, se eu conseguisse inserir 10 nomes nessa tela por exemplo seria perfeito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução seria colocar os inputs para enviar os valores como array.

Para isso você pode incluir e modificar estas linhas no arquivo html

```
<form method="POST" action="cadastro.php">
<label>Nome:</label><input type="text" name="nome[]" id="nome1"><br>
<label>Sobrenome:</label><input type="text" name="sobrenome[]" id="sobrenome1">
<br>
<label>Nome:</label><input type="text" name="nome[]" id="nome2"><br>
<label>Sobrenome:</label><input type="text" name="sobrenome[]" id="sobrenome2">
<br>
<label>Nome:</label><input type="text" name="nome[]" id="nome3"><br>
<label>Sobrenome:</label><input type="text" name="sobrenome[]" id="sobrenome3">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" id="cadastrar" name="cadastrar">
</form>
```

Você pode melhorar o visual, escondendo os campos por exemplo com css e ter um botão para faze-los aparecer, como não é foco da pergunta, não vou incluir isso.

E no arquivo PHP você pode utilizar um foreach ou um for para percorrer os arrays, neste caso, irei utilizar o for como exemplo.

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];

$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
$db = mysql_select_db('painel2');

for($i=0;$i < count($nome);$i++){
    $query_select = "SELECT nome FROM clientes WHERE nome = '$nome[$i]'";
    $select = mysql_query($query_select,$connect);
    $array = mysql_fetch_array($select);
    $logarray = $array['nome']; 

    if($nome[$i] == "" || $nome[$i] == null){
    echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('O campo nome deve ser preenchido');window.location.href='formulario.php';</script>";

    }else{
      if($logarray == $nome[$i]){

        echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Esse nome já existe');</script>";
          if($i == (count($nome)-1){
              die();
          }else{
              continue();
          }

      }else{
        $query = "INSERT INTO clientes (nome,sobrenome) VALUES ('$nome[$i]','$sobrenome[$i]')";
        $insert = mysql_query($query,$connect);

        if($insert){
          echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!');'</script>";
        }else{
          echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Não foi possível cadastrar esse cliente');'</script>";
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Não cheguei a testar, mas deve funcionar.

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Obrigado funcionou direitinho!